# Should Uno.Material be installed in pre-release Uno?

Tags: uno-platform

As Uno.Material is marked as a pre-release package, should the other Uno libraries' versions be upgraded to pre-release as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the 'Dependencies' tab in the [Uno.Material NuGet listing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Material/), you'll see that
Uno.Material requires (at time of writing) Uno.UI 3.0.0-dev.1533 or higher (which is the version it [happens to be built with](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Material/blob/aaf0e803b847f47cf7466f39096c90b9e4353a6d/src/library/Uno.Material/Uno.Material.csproj#L14)). Therefore you should be fine using the Uno.UI 3.1.6 stable release or higher.